# Magento 2.4. PHP 7.4.11 echo currency rate on CMS page

Tags: php, magento, magento2, currency, rate

I have CMS page on Magento 2.4 from admin_[secret]/cms/page/edit/page_id/1
I have base currency XAU, default Display Currency EUR. 1 XAU = 1460 EUR
How I can echo currency code and echo on cms page code like this?

```
<div id="bonus" class="XAU"><?=convert(1,XAU,EUR) + 10?></div> 
*<!-- 1XAU plus 10 EUR will echo "1470" like -->*
<div id="bonus" class="XAU">1470</div>
```

Can I make this without block creation?

Comment: *"Can I make this without block creation?"* - CMS pages just hold static (nominally) HTML code which is stored in the database, so no, you can't embed PHP code into CMS pages and have it interpreted.

Comment: Thank you, CD001. So, okay, I will insert widget with custom block, and my DIV id="bonus" will be there, inside block. Is there will possible to echo currency rate?